# How to run a .py from terminal with a pycharm environnement

Tags: python, pycharm

I'm a begginer i don't really know how is working Pycharm.

I'm trying to start a .py from the terminal :

`psyko@psyko-desktop:~/Python/Neural Network/FFNN$ python3.6 Build.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "Build.py", line 1, in <module>
    from stuff.gradient_descent import gradient_descent
  File "/home/psyko/Python/Neural Network/FFNN/stuff/gradient_descent.py", line 1, in <module>
    import numpy as np
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'numpy'
psyko@psyko-desktop:~/Python/Neural Network/FFNN$`

When I run this code into pycharm it works because numpy is downloaded. So i want to use the same environnement but on the terminal.

Plus whenever I start a new project i have to download again numpy... how to change that ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most probably Pycharm uses a virtual environment. The name of the virtual environment should be `env` or `venv`. You need to switch that environment. Find out it's name and switch to it.

Let's suppose your virtual environment name: `venv`. You can activate it via running below command in the cmd:

For windows:

```
venv\Scripts\activate.bat
```

For Linux:

```
source venv/bin/activate
```

Comment: I'm on ubuntu (forget to said it) i found a /venv/bin/activate but i don't know how to run it.

Comment: Just use source:

```source venv/bin/activate```

Comment: Thx, but when i try to run my .py file it still tell me that "import numpy as np
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'numpy'". I still use the command "python3.6 file.py"

Comment: Just type python? You can look where the python called from via which command. e.g. which python. It should called from virtual environment

Comment: It works ! Thx for helping me i really need to get better fast :)